# JTree node dosen't update after using a custom DefaultTreeCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtree

I have a JTree and a JtextField, So I have added listeners to The textfield so that if I Press Enter, the node is updated with the name entered in the field.

This works fine, the problem comes when I use a custom DefaultTreeCellRenderer to render disabled Nodes.After this I have to click manually to the node to see the change appear.

I did try reload(),nodeChanged() but no change.

The JTree panel:

```java
  public class RuleTree extends JPanel {
    private static JTree autoscoreRuleTree;
    private static DefaultTreeModel treeModel;


renameRule(){
    /*
        Code given below
    */
}

newRule(){
    /*
        Creates a new rule
    */
}

copyRule(){
    /*
        Copies a rule
    */
}

disableRule(){
    /*
        disables a rule codee given below
    */
}
```

The text field class:

```java
public class RuleNamePanel extends JPanel {
    private static JLabel ruleName;
    private static JTextField ruleNameTextField;

    /* To rename on pressing enter*/
            ruleNameTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    RuleTree.renameRule(ruleNameTextField.getText());
                }
            }
        });
```

The render class:  (Rule is a custom class)

```java
public class AutoScoreRuleTreeRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean exp, boolean leaf,
            int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, exp, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        Rule rule = (Rule) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
        this.setEnabled(rule.isActivated());

        return this;
    }

}
```

And this is called when I press enter on the text field

```java
public static void renameRule(String name) {
        TreePath nodeToRename = autoscoreRuleTree.getSelectionPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) nodeToRename.getLastPathComponent();
        Rule rule = (Rule) node.getUserObject();
        rule.setName(name);
        treeModel.nodeChanged(node);
    }
```

The buttons panel

```java
public class RuleModifyButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    private JButton newRuleButton;
    private JButton newChildButton;
    private JButton duplicateRuleButton;
    private JButton cutRuleButton;
    private JButton pasteRuleButton;
    private JButton disableRuleButton;

    /*
    Each button calls a method when clicked
    */

        //When disable button is pressed this will internally call enableNode method
        disableRuleButton.addActionListener(e -> RuleTree.disableRule()); 

    }
```

Disable Node Method

```java
    private static void enableNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, boolean enable) {
        autoscoreRuleTree.setCellRenderer(new AutoScoreRuleTreeRenderer());
        enablePanels(enable);
        Rule rule = (Rule) node.getUserObject();
    }
```

Expected to change on enter but changes when I manually click on the tree.

Before using render:
[Enter the name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kxbc.png) > [Pressed Enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxT3q.png)

After Using render:
[Enter the name after render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t32rh.png) > [Press Enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEhgz.png) > [Click manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spmSA.png)

Comment: The code, you've posted here, is not enough to find your error. Please provide a [mcve], so we can find your mistake and elaborate a solution.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy added more code, will this be enough?

Comment: No, because I cannot run it. Please create and post a [mcve].